# Adding list items into dictionary Python within a loop

Tags: python, list, selenium

So, within a loop, I have this list

```
     for fruit in fruits:
        driver.get(fruit)
        box_items_list =  [ ["shape:round"], ["water:no"]]
        # and I am adding the items to the 
        fruit_dict= {
                "fruit" : furit_name,
                "color" : color_name,
                "flavor" : flavor_type, 
        }
        dictionar_to_list.append(fruit_dict)
```

I am getting all the data using selenium from a website.
What I want to do is to add `box_items_list` items into `fruit_dict`
Such that:

```
        fruit_dict= {
                "fruit" : furit_name,
                "color" : color_name,
                "flavor" : flavor_type,
                "shape": "round",
                "water": "no" 
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `box_items_list` and then iterate over the `items` inside the list and then split them.

Here's the code:

```
for item in box_items_list:
    for i in item:
        values = i.split(":")
        fruit_dict[values[0]] = values[1]
```

Dummy output:

```
{'fruit': 'apple',
 'color': 'red',
 'flavor': 'any',
 'shape': 'round',
 'water': 'no'}
```

Comment: why would you call `i.split` twice? call it once and store it in a variable and then just index that variable. conversely, `key, value = i.split(":")` yields the same result

Comment: @gold_cy I've used it just to show `key` and `values` separately for clear understanding.

Comment: but it is performing an unneeded operation for a second time...